# Hardhat: how to deploy contract with an interface in constructor?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a contract called Token.sol

Inside there is an interface:

```
interface TokenInterface {
}
```

followed by the contract with constructor having that interface

```
contract Token {

  TokenInterface public tokenInterface;

  constructor(TokenInterface _tokenInterface) {
    tokenInterface = _tokenInterface;
  }
```

How do I deploy this in hardhat test? Right now I have

```
    Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
    [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();

    token = await Token.deploy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const Test = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestInterface");
const test = await Test.deploy();

const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const token = await Token.deploy(test.address);
```

once you deploy the constract that implements the interface you can get the address and pass it as a parameter to the deploy function as you can see in the example

[image]